# VBA to fill in VLOOKUP formula in Cell: Shows Error, What's wrong?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, vlookup

```
Sub ()

Cells(2, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count + 5).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet2'!$B$3:$BB$41,MATCH(RIGHT(R[-1]C,2),'Sheet2'!$B$3:$AZ$3,0),FALSE)"

End Sub()
```

Comment: you are mixing A1 and R1C1 notation.  This is not permissable.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is, in the formula, I want to refer to the cell immediaely above it, but if I type in the formula that works in the Excel: 

=VLOOKUP(A2;'Sheet1'!$B$3:$BB$41;MATCH(RIGHT(Table5[[#Headers];[Forecast 21]];2);'Sheet1'!$B$3:$AZ$3;0);FALSE)

VBA shows an error. 

Do you know how i can correc this?

Comment: you also need to change the `;` to `,` vba uses US-EN setting when using `.Formula`

Comment: Thanks! Works now.

One More question, If I want to change the Forecast 21 to Forecast 22 (in the next month), how do I make this number float? 

Right now it seems the formula only works for this month

Comment: `Table5[[#Headers];[Forecast " & monthvariable & "]]` Where monthvariable is a variable that you assign a value like `21` or `22` somehow.

Comment: Thanks Scott, let me try

Comment: Do I write:

Set monthvariable = 21 ? 
It says variable is not defined:

Cells(2, Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Count - 3).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$B$3:$BB$41,MATCH(RIGHT(Table5[[#Headers],[Forecast " & monthvariable & "]]],2),'Sheet1'!$B$3:$AZ$3,0),FALSE)"